# Good C library to parse apache log file

Tags: c, apache, parsing, logging

I would like to parse a lot of apache log files with a C library.

Who knows a good C library which is optimized for good performance?

Thank you for advice!

Comment: [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io) is a console program that generates reports from Apache log files. I can't tell if it provides a library and API, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try to [MergeLog](http://mergelog.sourceforge.net/) ? You can use the parser that comes with it.

Comment: MergeLog doesn't really parse Apache logs, it just scans for the date field so it can resort things (which is not a criticism, it does what it needs to do).  I'm still looking for something compiled that will actually parse Apache logs preferably taking the log format as input.